# Can I fly into a country and leave on the same plane?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, belarus, lithuania, timetables

I would like to visit Belarus for some time but they have a 5-day maximum stay (visa free) so I was hoping I could fly from Minsk (Belarus) to Vilnius (Lithuania) go through immigration and then run to the check-in counter, back through security, immigration and back to the plane that brought me.

The flights are about an hour apart. Would I have enough time?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your final deatination? Another city in Belarus? Or a different country? If it is another city in Belarus, you'll go, most probably, through immigration there...

Comment: If they even stamp.

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The commenters seem to have missed that Vilnius is not in Belarus. I think they are trying to do 5 days Visa-free in Belarus visit, 50 minute Lithuania stop, another 5 days Visa-free in Belarus.

Comment: What the OP is trying to do is make the shortest possible visa run from Belarus to Vilnius and back.

Comment: Good catch, @MarkPerryman. Though it seems to be hard to find a same-day return flight from Minsk to Vilnius that's cheaper than just applying for a Belarussian visa, so the plan still seems strange.

Comment: Where does the entry permit get issued? In Vilnius or during the arrival in Belarus? If it's during arrival, why fly in the first place? Just exit through passport control, turn around and go right back to immigration. If you can finagle a gate pass,  you may not need to by a ticket at all

Answer (score 7):

I doubt it - it’s highly likely checkin and/or the gate will have closed by the time you get there

Answer (score 7):

1) Visa free for Belarus (only when flying into Minsk) is now 30 days.

2) Even though Vilnius is a small airport, going out and back in passport control (you will also need to go through security again) will take too long as arrivals and departures are in separate buildings and levels.

TIP: If you are leaving Vilnius airport in a hurry, you can pay to go through fast track at security (off to the left). It costs 5 euro and can be billed to your phone or you can use cash/card at kiosk. Almost no one ever uses it, so you will likely be the only one.

Comment: OP can also fly to an airport where arrivals and departures are not segregated (Prague airport for example). In this case it will be easy to pull off.